# Can a One for All user transfer just one of his quirks to other users?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In the manga we found out that,

> The user of One for All has the previous quirks of the former users, meaning the current user (Midoriya) has at least 7 quirks

Can a One for All user transfer just one of his quirks to other users?

Comment: The new developments on One For All are blurring its line of difference compared to All For One. Such a transfer and stacking of multiple quirks is something All For One is capable of. As for OFA, Deku seems to be the first to have triggered such a manifestation (maybe due to gradual growth of what they called the "core" of OFA), so we'll have to wait and watch

Comment: Also minor correction, it would be at most 6 quirks. Deku and All Might being originally quirkless, while the first user's quirk being the 'transfer to others' power that brought OFA into existence on combination with the stockpile power.